# how to use combination for a coin flip

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

If there is a similar question, post it in the comments, please. Thank you.

If a coin is flipped 8 times, how many possible outcomes can at least 6 heads occur?

Comment: I think you mean how many of all possible outcomes. just a nitpick.

Comment: thanks, I did change it to make it a little clearer

Comment: Just compute the number with exactly $6$, exactly $7$, and exactly $8$ and add.

Comment: what would the math be for that? I have been having trouble with that part

Comment: hint binomial coefficients or Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

That is the probability function. You can just multiply it by the total outcome to get the desired answer.

Comment: "If a coin is flipped $8$ times, [in] how many possible outcomes can at least $6$ heads occur?"  Why are you calculating a probability?

Comment: You can multiply it by the total outcome to get the asked outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have flipped a fair coin eight times.   Each particular sequence (ie: outcome) has a probability of $2^{-8}$ for occurring.   All that is left is to count the outcomes for the event.

To count the outcomes using combinations, notice that you are counting ways the flips shall be heads.   That is: count selections of 6, 7, or 8 from 8 flips.

> $$\left(\binom 8 6+\binom 87 +\binom 88\right)\cdot \dfrac 1{2^8}$$

Where, as you likely know but to be sure: the *binomial coefficient*, $\binom nr$, counts ways to select $r$ elements from a set of $n$.$$\dbinom nr=\dfrac{n!}{r!~(n-r)!}$$

Comment: "If a coin is flipped $8$ times, [in] how many possible outcomes can at least $6$ heads occur?"  Why did you calculate a probability?